# Насколько стилистически корректно говорить "злобы дня"?

Tags: стилистика

Читал статью в Википедии и наткнулся на следующий фрагмент:

> > В это время он вступает на литературное поприще: в лионских журналах этого периода можно найти за его инициалами несколько стихотворений, а затем и статей, в которых обсуждались различные **злобы дня** и местные нужды.

Мне такое употребление резануло слух; я бы сформулировал *злободневные темы*.

Answer (score 4):

Это вопрос *соответствия общему стилю* текста: если он сам по себе цветист и изобилует выражениями типа "литературное поприще" (как в этом отрывке), то даже фрагментарное использование устойчивого выражения "**на злобу дня**" выглядит допустимым - лишь бы читатель, которому адресован текст, был знаком с происхождением этого выражения и понимал, что значат его части. А возникло оно из церковно-славянского текста Евангелия "довлеет дневи злоба его" (важны лишь насущные заботы дня), где "злоба" означает заботу или потребность. Отсюда понятно, что в исходном тексте "злобы дня" означает "актуальные темы/вопросы".

Comment: Отмечу, что выражение "злоба дня" в словаре фразеологизмов А.Н. Булыко выделено в отдельную статью со своим примером употребления. Поэтому нет необходимости рассматривать его как фрагмент другого выражения.

Comment: Там есть примеры с множественным числом?

Comment: Нет, я об этом не подумал. Пожалуй, я неправ :)

Answer (score 4):

Существительное ***злоба*** имеет полную парадигму склонения (по Зализняку), множественное число используется, хотя и не часто, например;

Есть значки политического характера, антивоенные, **на все злобы дня**.... [Виктор Розов. Удивление перед жизнью (1960-2000)]

...они помогали вспомнить волнения, интересы, **злобы дня прошедших лет**... [Леонид Утесов. «Спасибо, сердце!» (1982)]

С этой целью мы раза два-три в месяц сами составляли **на текущие злобы дня** «прокламации», которые сами и печатали. [В. М. Зензинов. Пережитое (1953)]

Возможно, что раньше  такая форма использовалась чаще и никого не удивляла. Потом появились ***злободневные темы***, но со временем  стали штампом и уже не очень интересны для автора.