# Выражение "злоба дня"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

Мне нужно написать четверостишие. Пишу о том, что сегодня непросто быть благородным поэтом. Правильно ли будет использовать выражение "в злобе дня" вместо слова "сегодня"?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/436905/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8f/436907#436907

Answer (score 1):

Нет, так нельзя. Есть выражение *"на злобу дня"* — на тему, которая особенно интересует всех в настоящее время. А это будет неудачной его переделкой.

Может быть, вам подойдёт: *в суете дня / в дневной суете, в дневных заботах*?

Comment: "Нет, так нельзя." - поэтам можно, если поэзия того требует )) Но надо на конечный результат смотреть, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

*На злобу "сёдняшнего" дня,

Вопрос Евгении храня,

Я написал такой ответ,

Который должен видеть свет.*